# Sumproduct formula in power bi

Tags: powerbi, sumproduct

I have a lookup table (Daily Target) for four employees (AA, BB, CC, DD).

Could you please help me to assign the target to Table 2 in the column 'Target'? Thanks a lot.

Daily Target

[image]

Table 2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So if the USER_ID does not exist in Source table, it can be also understood as the max(lastest) USER_ID in the additional table, right? If so, you can create a new USER_ID column in Source table using DAX below:

```
New USER_ID =
IF (
    'Source Table'[USER_ID] = RELATED ( 'Additional Table'[USER_ID] ),
    RELATED ( 'Additional Table'[USER_ID] ),
    MAX ( 'Additional Table'[USER_ID] )
)
```

[image]

Then you can create a measure based on the new USER_ID column to achieve the total result.

```
SUM #ORD =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Source Table'[# ORD] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Source Table', 'Source Table'[New USER_ID] )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to this would be to [unpivot those columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098) in the query editor to reshape the data.

If you really want a sumproduct style of solution, it might look something like this:

```
Target =
SUMX (
    FILTER ( DailyTarget, DailyTarget[Date] = EARLIER ( Table2[Date] ) ),
    SWITCH (
        EARLIER ( Table2[Name] ),
        "AA", DailyTarget[AA],
        "BB", DailyTarget[BB],
        "CC", DailyTarget[CC],
        "DD", DailyTarget[DD]
    )
)
```